# using html5 input type='color'

Tags: python, django, html, django-models

I have a model

```
# models.py
from django.db import models
    
class Foo(models.Model):
    # ...
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=True)
```

`color` should store a hex-color. Instead of a `input type="text"` I would like to use the [html5 input type "color"](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp).

I tried this by setting up the following form object:

```
# forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm, CharField

class FooForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        widgets = {
                   'color': CharField(attrs={'type': 'color'}),
                   }
```

However, this gives me the following error message

> **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'attrs'

What am I doing wrong and how would I do it right?

Comment: `attrs` is not an argument to the field, it's an argument to the widget.

Comment: ok, but aren't they doing it like this here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields? Or am I mixing up something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Solved it myself. It works nearly like I expected:

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):
    # ...
    color = models.CharField(max_length=7, null=True)

# forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django.forms.widgets import TextInput

class FooForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        widgets = {
                   'color': TextInput(attrs={'type': 'color'}),
                   }
```

The part that was tricky for me was not to forget to set it up right in the view:

```
# views.py
from my_app.models import Foo
from my_app.forms import FooForm

class FooCreate(CreateView):
    model = Foo
    form_class = FooForm
```

Thanks to [aamir-adnan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/860103/aamir-adnan) - he pointed out that I have to use TextInput instead of CharField.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to update the `type` attr, you need to update the widget attrs which is a [TextInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.TextInput) for [CharField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#charfield):

```
class FooForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
        super(FooForm, self).__init__(*args, **kw)
        self.fields['color'].widget.attrs.update({
            'type': 'color',
        })

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
```

Comment: Thank you! Using a `TextInput` instead of a `CharField` at least gives me no error (still I don't understand completely why a `CharField`is not possible). The doc also says " It is also possible to specify the ‘type’ attribute to take advantage of the new HTML5 input types. To do this, you use the Widget.attrs argument when creating the widget" (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/forms/widgets/#styling-widget-instances). Wouldn't that be more straight forward (however, I don't succeed trying that).

Comment: I don't know how you have used the TextInput widget. But if you follow my solution it should work, see i am doing `widget.attrs.update` which is actually updating attr of `TextInput` widget of a `CharField` of `color`